# Bluemix Continuous Delivery deploy script pass env variables

Tags: ibm-cloud, devops, devops-services

I need to pass some environment variables to the deploy script like user names and spaces, service plans, etc. The idea was to use env in the `manifest.yml` file, but I can't get that working - seems like I can only use the predefined CF_APP etc.

Any tips on passing stuff to the deploy script?

Espen

Comment: How were you adding the environment variables via the manifest?

Answer (score 0):

You can define your own environment variables in manifest.yml file.

```
env:
  <var-name>: <value>
  <var-name>: <value>
```

Checkout this link https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/manifest.html to see in details the fields available in manifest.yml.

Comment: You can also use `cf set-env APP_NAME ENV_VAR_NAME ENV_VAR_VALUE`, also listed in the above link, if you need to set CF env vars from your environment.